# Flutter: Compare String to List<String> Callback doesn't work

Tags: string, flutter, dart, callback, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a function to compare if the string contains a list of keywords (string list)
I implement it as a callback function from another widget in flutter.
The callback function works, however, the compare method inside callback function doesn't work.

Please send help /.\

```
  void callback(List<String> filterKeyword) {
    setState(() {
      this.filterKeyword = filterKeyword;
    });
    resFiltered.clear();
    res.forEach((res) {
      if (compareString(res.type, this.filterKeyword)) {
        resFiltered.add(res);
      }
    });
  }

  bool compareString(String inputStr, List<String> items) {
    if (items.length == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if(inputStr.contains(items[i])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Can you add values for which function is not working?

Comment: I think your code is working.
Please show the minimum code that doesn't work.

Comment: The not working values: inputStr = "Chinese,Japanese,Thai" items = ["Chinese"]

Comment: The compareString function was called but never execute.

Comment: Thus, resFiltered is empty

Answer (score 0):

I changed it little bit to return string and implemented added to flutter default project as text widget. And it worked. You have to ensure if the parameters where indeed as you written... I notice that this is case sensitive...

[image]

I hope it will help!